# How to Hide/Show Overflow Icon in ToolBar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

how to hide/show overflow icon in custom Toolbar programmatically.

Thanks,
Petros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
if (!showIcon)
    return false;
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Now, whenever you want to show the overflow icon just make showIcon variable true otherwise false.

Comment: Thanks bro for big help !
I don't have permission for vote so I can't raise up your answer. Sorry

Comment: Welcome @PetrosMosoyan I am happy to help you.  _Happy Coding!_